# ASP.Net @Html.TextBox Datepicker

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I am trying to put in a datepicker on a @Html.TextBox. The date field is to be used as a search criteria field so that I can compare a date entry to a date in the table. This is what I have for my scripts:

```
<link href="~/Content/ui_1.10.4_themes_smoothness_jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src=" ~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#getdate").each(function () {
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```

This is what I have for my TextBox:

```
Date Received: @Html.TextBox("SearchString5",  new {@class="getdate"}, ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
```

What it results in is that the words `new {@class="getdate"}` showing up in the TextBox.

Comment: Try ".getdate" rather than #getdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole code looks buggy, first of all you are adding a class getdate and in jquery you are using id selector

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#getdate").each(function () {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
});
```

this should be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".getdate").each(function () {
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```

Second thing you are missing value parameter in helper, it should be like this

```
Date Received: @Html.TextBox("SearchString5",ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string,  new {@class="getdate"})
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because your parameters are messed up for the overloaded method of `Html.TextBox`..

They should be like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    object value,
    string format,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

so with your specific case:

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString5",ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new {@class="getdate"})
```

Also, in your JS, you are referencing an `ID` with the `#`.. but rather you need to reference a `class` with a `.`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".getdate").each(function () {
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your order of parameters is not correct. It should be like, first element name, then value and then html attributes. write it this way:

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString5",ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new {@class="getdate"})
```

See [this overload in documentation at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29)

and now in jquery use class selector, as id should be unique for each element for html:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".getdate").each(function () {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Thank-you everyone. I had tried the .getdate previously however I had the last two parameters in the wrong order. I got my datepicker however my date search still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your last two parameters are in the wrong order

Try:

```
Date Received: @Html.TextBox("SearchString5",ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string,  new {@class="getdate"})
```

Also your jquery is looking for `id=getdate` but your html is specifying the class as `getdate`

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect parameter order. It should be:

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString5", "6/30/2016", new { @class="getdate" })
```

See this overload form:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29

Comment: just wondering, wouldn't there need to be `null` parameter in between the value and the htmlAttributes?

Comment: That's just another overload form to accept `format` parameter. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object,System.String,System.Object%29 Although both work why do we need to pass an argument that is `null`?